# Como llamar una clase privada desde una clase publica

Tags: java, android

Tengo la siguiente `clase privada`:

```
private class sendReportePeriodico extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        socket = null;
        SocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(server_address, server_port);
        socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(address, 3000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Can't Connect";
        }
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);

        output.print(texto);
        output.flush();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Necesito `llamar` esta clase `dentro` de esta una `clase publica`:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("LogXXX","Visualizando gps");
    texto = "GPS: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude();
    tvMensaje.setText(texto);
    mapa(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    AQUI NECESITO LLAMAR LA CLASE PRIVADA;
 }
```

Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Las clases `private` no existen en Java.

Comment: Igual no existen las clases con modificador `private`.

Comment: La idea de haber hecho una clase privada es que no se pueda instanciar desde afuera de la clase que la contiene. Si `sendReportePeriodico` no es una clase interna entonces me parece que copiaste un ejemplo sin entender muy bien la idea de las clases internas privadas. Además dado el nombre que le pusiste a la clase suena como que solo necesitas un método que cumpla una funcionalidad específica.

Comment: suponiendo que realmente fuera privada tu clase la forma de accederla sería con un accesor (getter por ejemplo), ahora lo más sensato para mantener la encapsulación es mediante un delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

Tu clase en realidad es un `AsyncTask`

```
private class sendReportePeriodico extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

aunque esta definida la clase como `private` debes llamarlo de esta forma

```
new sendReportePeriodico().execute("");
```

Answer (score 0):

`private class sendReportePeriodico extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`

Esto no debería compilar, ya que no existen las clases `private` en java, deberías cambiarlo por

`public class sendReportePeriodico`